# How to restore "view item" web part for Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 foundation.  We have a list available on the site that we use to manage work items.  Normally, the options to view detailed list content are "View Item" and "Edit Item".  It looks like someone accidentally deleted the list view for the "view item" page, so that when anyone opens an item, all they see is the list item title and a big blank box in the middle.  Does anyone know how to restore the list view for a single list item so that we can view the item contents?

[image]

Comment: Restore an earlier version of the .aspx page. Pref. the last major version.

Comment: that only seems to be an option for individual list items, not views.

Comment: You said someone deleted a webpart; I assumed this was on an aspx page with webpart zones. There was no word of a deleted listview in your question. you should clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, Serv.  Not a sharepoint expert by any means.  Apologies for using the wrong terminology.  Edited question

Comment: Wait a second, do you mean a listview, or do you mean a list form? for exmaple EditForm.aspx NewForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Whatever would display normally when I click on an individual list item and choose "View Item".  That page that shows the overview of the item in detail.  I think that might be DispForm.aspx?

Comment: The dispform.aspx loads but there is no content in the main section.

Comment: I've answered you on how to recreate the standard disp form for a list view. If you have extensivly modified this form template, you either have a backup OR you have to recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright; if your form was a non modified-form without further extensions or modifications you have only a few clicks ahead of you, otherwise: you better have a backup.

Disclaimer: I am using the german version of SPD, but the controls are at the same positions as in the English version. See screenshots for clarifications

1. Open up SharePoint Designer 2010
2. Open your SP Site
3. Open the list in question
4. Click on "new" (see Screenshot below)
   [image]
5. Fill out the form (Enter name, check form to view, and default form)
   [image]
6. Boom - you're good to go again. Save it.

You can download SPD here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573